# Count if a value exists inside the array of objects [ MongoDB ]

Tags: mongodb

I am developing a simple chat application with MongoDB and got stuck into a situation.

My document in database is as

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("605a217ed8168f4c262f4782"),
  "message" : "Hi, This is a test message",
  "created" : ISODate("2021-03-23T17:12:30.000Z"),
  "user" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5977af7df1d8cc4623283b14"),
    "name" : "Sender Of Message"
  },
  "recipients" : [ 
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5977af7df1d8cc4623283b14"),
      "time" : ISODate("2021-03-23T17:12:30.000Z")
    }, 
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5df50a5eaa0e3c3104006101"),
      "time" : ISODate("2021-03-23T17:12:35.000Z")
    }
  ],
  "target" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df50a5eaa0e3c3104006101"),
    "name" : "Target Person"
  },
  "status" : 1
}
```

When I try to get the last message with the unread count of the user I am always getting 1

Here is the query that I tried on.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { 'target._id': ObjectId('5df50a5eaa0e3c3104006101'), status: 1 } },
  { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$user._id',
      doc: { $first: '$$ROOT' },
      unread: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: { $ne: [ ObjectId('5df50a5eaa0e3c3104006101'), '$recipients._id' ] },
            then: 1,
            else: 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If the collection contains even just the one document above, it is supposed to give 0 as the object inside the `recipients` array already contains the `_id` as `ObjectId('5df50a5eaa0e3c3104006101')`, but I'm getting 1 for the unread count. Any help?

Here is the output that I get from the query

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5977af7df1d8cc4623283b14"),
  "doc" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("605a217ed8168f4c262f4782"),
    "message" : "Hi, This is a test message",
    "created" : ISODate("2021-03-23T17:12:30.000Z"),
    "user" : {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5977af7df1d8cc4623283b14"),
      "name" : "Sender Of Message"
    },
    "recipients" : [ 
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5977af7df1d8cc4623283b14"),
        "time" : ISODate("2021-03-23T17:12:30.000Z")
      }, 
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5df50a5eaa0e3c3104006101"),
        "time" : ISODate("2021-03-23T17:12:35.000Z")
      }
    ],
    "target" : {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5df50a5eaa0e3c3104006101"),
      "name" : "Target Person"
    },
    "status" : 1
  },
  "unread" : 1.0
}
```

I know why its showing with the count as `1`

> The array `recipients` contains an object with `_id` as `ObjectId("5977af7df1d8cc4623283b14")` inside it, so its a non matching condition. Which is causing the if condition to be satisfied and produce a value `1`.

But I need to figure out how to query it to get the actual value.

*Please note that I cant use `$push` operator on `recipients` array as it might have greater amount of object ( maybe in future )*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support, but I have found the answer by myself.
Here is my approch to get the data as per the requirement.

Instead of searching for the records within the array what I did is

1. Filtered the data array to the `_id` that I don't need, so the array will have exactly one document or else it will be empty.
2. When taking the negation of the condition. ie, when there is one value in the array I need the counter to be 0 or else it should be 1
3. So I used the [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) to check the array's size and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to filter out the other `_id`s and then used [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to increment the counter as required.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { 'target._id': ObjectId('5df50a5eaa0e3c3104006101'), status: 1 } },
    { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$user._id',
            doc: { $first: '$$ROOT' },
            unread: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond:{
                        if: {
                            $size: {
                                $filter: {
                                    input: '$recipients',
                                    as: 'item',
                                    cond: { $eq: [ ObjectId('5df50a5eaa0e3c3104006101'), '$$item._id' ] }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        then: 0,
                        else: 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to Use like this:

```
   db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    { $match: { 'target._id': ObjectId('5df50a5eaa0e3c3104006101'), status: 1 
     } },
     { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
      { $unwind: { path: "$recipients", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
       {
         $group: {
           _id: '$user._id',
           doc: { $first: '$$ROOT' },
           unread: {
              $sum: {
                $cond: {
                  if: { $ne: ['$recipients._id', 
                   ObjectId('5df50a5eaa0e3c3104006101') ] },
                   then: 1,
                   else: 0
                  }
                }
               }
              }
             } 
           ])
```

Comment: Its still giving me `1` as the output. As I said, its matching with the `ObjectId("5977af7df1d8cc4623283b14")` as it is not equal to `ObjectId('5df50a5eaa0e3c3104006101')`

Comment: Also as per the docs for [$ne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ne/) it doesn't specify the position of the operator vs value. It only states as `{ $ne: [ <expression1>, <expression2> ] }`

Comment: try using above query

Comment: Its an error `"Unrecognized expression '$nor'"`

Comment: I undetstood the logic you applied here, but the issue is the array `recipients` will have more than 2 objects as I have already mentioned as `it might have greater amount of object ( maybe in future )`. In those case this logic will fail

Comment: you need to unwind it then group it . I have edited it for you above

Comment: It will be extremely slow if `recipients` array is too large and if there are many documents with different `user._id`. As it's for chat, there can be pretty good amount of documents.

Comment: After `$unwind` if I group and find the `unread` count using the `if` condition, all the others except the one that wont match in the same document will be counted as unread.. ie, if a document have 500 recipients and if I have the exeact document within the array, then 499 will be the unread count.

Comment: yes It will be slow but acc. to your model I am able to figure out only this soln.

Comment: It will never be accurate. see the comment

Comment: If you don't want to use it like this try to maintain read count inside recipient array

Comment: Can you provide an example?